# LangChain: Why is inference on GPU slower than on CPU?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers, langchain

I am still quite new to LLMs, LangChain, etc. so please excuse if this is stupid question, but I have started to tinker with running LLMs locally via Python, LangChain etc, but am wondering about the following and maybe someone can guide me/explain why this is happening and how to resolve it:

I am running the model 'lmsys/fastchat-t5-3b-v1.0' locally on my PC (RTX 2060 with 6GB memory, AMD Ryzen 5, 32 GB RAM) using the code given here (HuggingFacePipeline): https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2023/06/23/hugging-face-run-llm-model-locally-laptop/
I run it under Windows in WSL (Debian). I have pytorch for CUDA installed.

When i ran the code as is, i noticed, that RAM and CPU usage went high and GPU VRAM was not used at all (using Windows Task Manager). Inference took ~ 32 seconds for my question "Describe some famous landmarks in London. Keep the answers short.".

I stumbled upon https://github.com/lm-sys/FastChat and just ran the same model as before i downloaded via their library (python3 -m fastchat.serve.cli --model-path ...). It used the GPU and also felt much faster. ~10 seconds for inference on the same question.

Knowning that it should be able to run on the GPU and be much faster, i went back to the original code and tinkered around with it. I understood that there is the accelerate library which i can use by setting device_map="auto". I also tried devide=0 to force it to use the GPU according to the documentation.

So, i tried these two variants:

```
llm = HuggingFacePipeline.from_model_id(
    model_id=model_id,
    task="text2text-generation",
    #device_map="auto",
    device=0,
    model_kwargs={"temperature": 0, "max_length": 1000},
)
```

The outcome was the following:
With device_map=auto, it still fully ran on the CPU
With device=0 ran on the GPU but inference was even slower. ~39 seconds.

Why is that? Is fastchat under the hood not using the same libraries? (pytorch, transformers, ...) So, should i be able to get the same level of performance for inference with langchain as with fastchat?
Even when not comparing with fastchat, why is it that for my example inference on the GPU is slower than on the CPU?

Comment: Have you checked that your input tensor is on the correct device?

Comment: I used the code example from this page as is and ran it: https://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2023/06/23/hugging-face-run-llm-model-locally-laptop/
There are no tensors i am directly instanciating. It uses langchain and huggingfacepipeline. The only way i found to influence were it runs is via the device/device_map settings.

Comment: have you checked if your gpu is available: 
`device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print("Training on:", device)`

if it is available try passing "cuda:0" as the device parameter

Comment: yes, cuda:0 is available. but to the device parameter i am already giving device: 0 which is the cuda device index. I am not able to give it a string.